# Help with understanding list function

Tags: python

When I type the following into the interpreter I get the desired output behavior:

```
>>> x = (7, 2, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 6)
>>> y = list(x)
>>> y
[7, 2, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 6]
```

Above, I simply converted a tuple to a list. However, when I run the following code I get an answer that I don't understand.

```
pwm = input("enter PWM: ")
npwm = pwm.replace('),(', ', ')
y = list(npwm)
print(y)
```

Output:

```
['(', '7', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '6', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '6', ')']
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening? Why does the above code not product the desired output of:

```
[7, 2, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 6]
```

EDIT: Wow, I can't thank everyone enough for the help! I greatly appreciate everyone's patients and willingness to help with my beginner questions. Thank you very much. Below is the solution that I got to worked:

```
pwm = (7, 2, 1, 1),(6, 2, 1, 2),(1, 2, 2, 6)  
npwm = pwm.replace('),(',', ').strip('(').strip(')')  
y = list(ast.literal_eval(npwm))  
print(y)
```

Comment: You should include the input. We can guess it in this case, but usually it's very important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `list` on a string, it generates a list in which each character is an item in the list. So for example:

```
>>> list("hey, you")
['h', 'e', 'y', ',', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u']
```

Since the data returned from `input` in this case is a string, calling `list` on it generates a list of characters.

For the sake of demonstration, here's a basic way to convert the string `'(1, 2, 3)'` into the list `[1, 2, 3]`:

```
>>> pwm = raw_input("enter PWM: ")
enter PWM: (1, 2, 3)
>>> pwm
'(1, 2, 3)'
>>> npwm = pwm.strip('(').strip(')')
>>> npwm
'1, 2, 3'
>>> npwm = npwm.split(',')
>>> npwm
['1', ' 2', ' 3']
>>> y = [int(x) for x in npwm]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3]
```

Some people have suggested using `eval` on the string returned by `input`. Although that would do what you want, it's a very bad habit to get into, because python will then evaluate whatever expression the (possibly malicious) user decides to enter.

Also, as Sven Marnach correctly pointed out, `input` does what you expect in python 2.x. Fortunately that's been corrected in 3.0, which you must be using.

Comment: This is only half of the issue. Inferring the input from the output shows that OP propably wants to effectively `eval` a tuple read from the user.

Comment: @delnan, true -- I added some detail.

Comment: Also, note unutbu's comment about `literal_eval`.

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic response. I greatly appreciated the easy to understand answer.

Answer (score 3):

A safe (more restrictive) alternative to using `eval` is [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
pwm = raw_input("enter PWM: ")
y = list(ast.literal_eval(pwm))
print(y)
```

Running

```
% test.py
enter PWM: (7), (2), (1), (1), (6), (2), (1), (2), (1), (2), (2), (6)
```

yields

```
[7, 2, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 6]
```

Note doing it this way avoids the fragile (and hard-to-read) `replace('),(',',')`, which only works when there is no space after the comma. E.g. `(7),(2)` instead of `(7), (2)`.

Comment: +1, good point -- I knew something like this existed but I couldn't remember where.

Comment: very cool.  thanks for pointing out the ast.literal_eval function. i had no idea that existed!

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the difference between data and source code. pwm will hold the string you have typed in, not a tuple. If you put a string into the list function, you will get back a list with the single characters of the string. That's what you get in your output.

Answer (score 0):

You are making string from string and then you convert string to list. What are you looking as final result is list from string.

Result you posted in beginning is not string but a presentation of list. It is list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
y = list(eval(npwn))
```

Comment: Noooooooo! (in the voice of Darth Vader). Avoid this!

Comment: Obviously `eval` can be dangerous if misused, but if the code is never going to leave his PC, it's quite harmless...

Comment: Just like handguns are harmless if they never leave the closet. Yes, that's a drastic analogy. But still, bad habits shouldn't be taught at all (without the appropriate warnings and instructions), regardless of how serious the danger is for the planned use case. Not only quite some prototypes make it into production, bad habits carry over.